# Peformance of selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select a element that meets certain criteria. Right now I'm doing it like this:

`$('[' + attr + '="' + name + '"]', el).filter('[type!="hidden"]').get(idx);`

which is slow as hell (1400ms in Opera, ~120ms in Chrome)

Before this I had:

`$('[' + attr + '="' + name + '"][type!="hidden"]', el).get(idx);`

which was taking like 5-6 seconds in Opera.

(the function that has this code is called like 250-400 times in a page)

Anyway, it's still slow because I'm doing many selects and the total load can still exceed 2 seconds in Opera, depending on the page content.

Do you think I can improve the query a little bit?

ps: "attr" has the `name` value (name attribute), I just had it as a variable to test if other attributes are faster

Comment: I assume that you want to select input elements, so you can add `input[attr=value]` and you will search only thru input tags, not all  in the page.

Comment: "this code is called like 250-400 times in a page". Well that might have something to do with it.

Comment: I know, but the problem is that some elements depend on other elements, so I must do all kind of cross-checks, which force me call this function 7-8 times the number of actual input elements on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a tag selector.  This way the browser can offload some of the effort to `getElementsByTagName` instead of filtering over ALL elements.  I'm guessing `input` based on the `type=hidden` qualifier.

```
$(el).find('input[' + attr + '="' + name + '"]').filter('[type!="hidden"]').get(idx);

//Don't actually call this too often unless the DOM is changing.  Cache it and then call the get function.
var resultSet = $(el.getElementsByTagName("input"))
    .add(el.getElementsByTagName("select"))
    .add(el.getElementsByTagName("textarea"))
    .filter(function() {
        //You may need to modify this section.  select and textarea don't have a type attribute.
        return this.getAttribute(attr) == name && this.getAttribute("type") == "hidden";
    });

//Call later
resultSet.get(idx);
```

Comment: the problem is that I need this on `input, textarea, select` not just `input` :) I'm afraid to add 3 selectors, it will probably get even worse

Comment: What does the type attribute mean for select and textarea?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the ability to modify the markup itself on the back-end, add a common class to each of these elements.  Then you can simply select by class which is much faster.

Additionally, if your page is large, but these inputs are only in one part of the screen, use a common parent to narrow it down.  `$("#parent <otherselector>")`

Comment: I could add a class on all of them before I'm doing my thing (with jquery). tx I'll try